# Why do I get an error saying curl: no URL specified error while pulling a tweet?

Tags: html, curl, twitter, terminal, command-prompt

Aim: To pull data using a tweet id

```
C:\Users\dell>curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer https://twitter.com/KanganaTeam/status/1328213589698592768"
```

But I'm getting this error

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a complete curl command. You've included the URL inside of the authorization header parameter.

You need something like this:

`curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer YOURBEARERTOKEN" https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/1328213589698592768.json`

Comment: Should we keep YOURBEARERTOKEN as it is?

Comment: No, you need to replace that with your API bearer token that you received in the developer portal when you created your app.